# How do I reasoning matrix of size n to get the big-o?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

The following very simple algorithm calculates the determinant of a matrix in a recrusive fashion with no optimization at all. Count how many operations (+, -, * and /) are done for a matrix of size n to get an estimate of the big-O of this algorithm based on FLOPS if you were using this algorithm to solve a system of equations using Cramer's Method. Detail your reasoning and counting carefully. While you may want to consider systems of equations of increasing size your final answer must be for a system of arbitrary size n.

function minors_det(A)
% get size of matrix A
d=0
N=size(A)

if N=2
d=A(1,1)*A(2,2)-A(1,2)*A(2,1)
else
   for i=1:N
   d=d+(-1)^(1+i)*A(1,i)*minors_det(submatrix(A,i));
end;
end;
return d;

Note that submatrix() function takes a matrix A and removes row 1 and column i to create a new smaller matrix.
A(i,j) refers to the element in the i^{th} rows and j^{th} column of A

Answer (score 0):

If $t_n$
is the op count for a
$n$ by $n$ matrix,
then

$t(n)
=n\,(t(n-1)+s(n))
$,
where
$s(n)$
is the time for
"submatrix".

Since submatrix
has to move
$(n-1)^2$
matrix elements,
$s(n)
= O(n^2)
$.

Therefore
$t(n)
=nt(n-1)+O(n^3)
$.

I will let you solve this.

Hint:
Do not use this method
for large $n$.